# Apache POI set permisson region in .docx document

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

*What do I mean by "permission region"? You can protect whole document by making it read-only, but you can leave regions that could be edited.*

I'm trying to define permission region in some `.docx` document. As far as I see, there is no API in POI library for doing it - the only thing I've found is permisson related methods in [`CTP`](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/src-html/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTP.html) class, but I don't have any idea how to work with it. My goal is to include one or more [`XWPFRun`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html) into the permission region to produce something like:

```
<w:permStart w:edGrp="everyone" w:id="1371696447"/>
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="28"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
        <w:lang w:val="cs-CZ"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>test3</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:permEnd w:id="1371696447"/>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution. I don't know, if it is the best way to do it, but it works fine for me:

```
// get DOM nodes of paragraph containing target run
// and run itself
Node paragraphNode = paragraph.getCTP().getDomNode();
Node runNode = run.getCTR().getDomNode();

// generate random id for perm region
String id = Integer.toString(this.random.nextInt());

// create starting node, set id and who can edit it
CTPermStart permStart = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPermStart();
permStart.setId(id);
permStart.setEdGrp(STEdGrp.EVERYONE);
Node permStartNode = permStart.getDomNode();

// create ending node and set id
CTPerm permEnd = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPermEnd();
permEnd.setId(id);
Node permEndNode = permEnd.getDomNode();

// enclose target run with created start/end nodes
paragraphNode.insertBefore(permStartNode, runNode);
paragraphNode.insertBefore(permEndNode, runNode.getNextSibling());
```